# Gitlab autodevops and Kubernetes, add the configuration file for angular on review pod

Tags: angular, kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-autodevops

I have an angular project that I try to review using gitlab-ci autodevops feature in a Kubernetes cluster.
The application runs fine in the review step. But to customize the backend, I need to put a file in the `assets/config` folder at runtime. The content of the file should be a CI/CD variable of gitlab.

I tried this with my `.gitlab-ci.yml` but the file is not sent to the running pod, and the angular application uses the default value of the api

```
include:
  - template: Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

review:
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ./src/assets/config && echo "$CONFIG_JSON" > ./src/assets/config/config.json
```

with `CONFIG_JSON` value as

```
{
    "api" : "http://<API IP>:9090"
}
```

What am I missing for my file to be available in the review pod ?

Background: I'm new to Gitlab, Kubernetes and Helm.

Comment: Well, what behavior **are** you experiencing? And be aware that since angular is a JS framework, 127.0.0.1 will be the user's computer, not the angular webapp's Pod

Comment: @mdaniel This was a template to hide the real IP. The angular app uses the default IP and not the one I try to put in the config.json.
I'll change the IP to not mislead